# How do I count the number of characters in a string in NASM?

Tags: string, count, character, nasm

I want to take an input and display the input with how many characters are in the string.
So far I'm able to produce the string, but I'm confused as to how I get the input?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function:

```
count db 0; (or resb 1), this is the place where will stay the result 

count_string:

    lodsb;                          // load char( letter )
    cmp al, 0x00;                   // check string end; cause 0x00 its not a letter or number, 0 is 30h in ascii
    jz done;                        // count done

    inc byte [count]; adds 1 to count register
    jmp count_string;               // check next char

    done:

        ret;                        // exit function
```

And you can define a string this way:

```
data:
    ; or in the section .data

    string DB "This is my string", 0; 0 means the end of the string
```

you can call the function this way:

```
mov si, string; move the string pointer to register
call count_string;
```

and if you are using nasm inside a OS like windows or ubuntu uou can watch this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VAy4FGHDx1I

but in x86 i did a 4 byte( for letters ) command line, its really easy to get much more but it was just a quick experiment i used int 16h( keyboard )

Comment: `inc count` is not valid NASM syntax, you want `inc byte [count]`